# Show dates against each un-pivoted column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written this query to convert columns into the rows.

```
select [ProjectName], EachDay, Hours
from [dbo].[TimeSheet_Child] 
unpivot
(
  Hours
  for EachDay in ([Mon], [Tue], [Wed])
) u
```

but instead of EachDay I need dates that comes between the start and end of the week e.g.

Currently:

```
ProjectName  EachDay     Hours
A            Mon          2
B            Tue          8
C            Wed          1
```

Should be

```
ProjectName   EachDay       Hours
A            15Dec2019        2
B            16Dec2019        8
C            17Dec2019        1
```

To pick dates between week start and end I have written this.

```
Declare @Year   int
,@Week int
,@YearText varchar(4)

set @Year = 2019
set @Week = 51

set @YearText = @Year

Declare @Increment int
Set @Increment= 1

declare @date datetime
Set @date= dateadd(day
             ,@Increment - datepart(dw, @YearText + '-01-01')
                + (@Week-1) * 7
             ,@YearText + '-01-01')
print @date

While (@Increment < 8)
Begin
              print dateadd(day
             ,@Increment - datepart(dw, @YearText + '-01-01')
                + (@Week-1) * 7
             ,@YearText + '-01-01')

              Set @Increment= @Increment + 1
End
```

Comment: I suggest you stick to one question instead of deleting and reposting similar questions multiple times.

Comment: Re your question: create a table variable that would map days of week to numbers e.g. `( 'Mon', 1 ), ( 'Tue', 2 ), ( 'Wed', 3 ), ....` join this table to your `unpivot` result to get "numbered" days of week. You can now use a simple `DATEADD( DAY, [DayOfWeekNum] - 1, [StartDateOfWeek] )`